# fail to retrieve parent for item in string

Tags: android

My project gives fail to run and gives error in retrieving parent for item

**Error** is as

```
 Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar at line 3
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="NoAnimation.Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"    parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>        
</style>

<style name="transparent_progress">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>


<style name="NotificationText">
  <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="NotificationTitle">
  <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="Registration.Description" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">16.0sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff333333</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
</style>

<style name="Registration.Label" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">12.0sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff808080</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
</style>

<style name="Registration.BigLabel" parent="@style/Registration.Label">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Registration.Constant" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff808080</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>        
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: have u tried clean and build your project ?

Comment: What if you remove the @style for the parent attribute like so: parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"

Answer (score 0):

In the ActionBarSherlock example he does not include the "@style/" in the parent attribute.
See example here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html

I can't verify right now but I think the following change might work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="NoAnimation.Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"    parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>        
</style>
```